# willPresentActionSheet two different action sheets in one class. How to know which one will present

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet

In my class I need to have 2 different (or more) actionsheets.  All of the sheets go to willPresentActionSheet. In willPresentActionSheet I do things like add a datepicker.  But how do I know which actionsheet called the willPresentActionSheet?

**EDIT:  I created the actionsheet like this:**

```
UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                         initWithTitle:@"Pick a value" 


                         delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                         destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                         otherButtonTitles:@"Select"
                         , nil];

[asheet showInView:[self.view superview]]; 

[asheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 383)];
[asheet release];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the 'tag' for the action sheets, and check the tag in `willPresentActionSheet:` method. Simple!

**Edit:** 
Set the tag.

```
actionSheet1.tag = 100;
actionSheet2.tag = 101;
```

And in `willPresentActionSheet:` method.

```
if (actionSheet.tag == 100) {  
    // actionSheet1 is going to be presented
} else if (actionSheet.tag == 101) {
    // actionSheet2 is going to be presented
}
```

Comment: yes but that is AFTER the fact.  How do I know what tag I am setting for which actionsheet?

Comment: I found how to create the tag when I create the actionsheet.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It passes the actionsheet into the method... So if you have (declared in the header) actionView1 and actionView2 then you can do...

```
if([actionSheet isEqual:actionView1]) {
  // do stuff for 1
} else if([actionSheet isEqual:actionView2]) {
  // do stuff for 2
}
```

Comment: ... and then you can distinguish the actionsheets by their tag (which you have the set on creation). This works because UIActionSheet is a subclass of UIView.

Comment: I am new to iPhone and havent quite got a handle on everything yet.  I added the code above in my question that shows how I started the ActionSheet. What do I need to do differently to declare this in the header?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the tag method but it's a perfectly good approach.

Comment: Tags seems to be set in the willPresentActionSheet, but I need to know which actionsheet it is. I see that the title is something that is set, can I use that?

Comment: OK I found that I can set the tag when I create the ActionSheet.  Thanks for the idea!